# Compare 2 set of cells and count

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make something of a pattern recognize counting cell and calculate their probability of occurrence.

Set 1 is from a database that looks like this (consists of 6+1 columns):

```
ABABAB   1
CACACA   2
CACACA   2
CACACA   2
CACACA   1
ABABAB   1
```

Set 2 is what I input manually (only 6 columns, without the 7th column information)

```
CACACA
```

If I want to know the probability of the 7th column as "2", pattern recognize counting cell should return 75, where if its "1" it should return 25.

Been cracking my brain using countifs function but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm afraid that makes absolutely no sense at all. Please add a small example table, indicating clearly in which cell each entry lies, together with your expected results.

Comment: Do you mean **rows** instead of **columns**? Because this is what I see when I look at your provided info.

Comment: This is my answer if I understood you correctly. I have put your given 6 rows into `A1:B6`. The following **array formula** evaluates to 0,75: `=SUM((A1:A6="CACACA")*(B1:B6=2))/COUNTIF(A1:B6,"CACACA")`. The following  - to 0,25: `=SUM((A1:A6="CACACA")*(B1:B6=1))/COUNTIF(A1:B6,"CACACA")`. Let me know if it helped and I would post it as the answer.

Comment: Yeah I guess I wasn't clear enough since I posted this with a burnout brain, thanks pal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you have seven columns, like this:

[image]

You would like to make a ratio between a combination that includes all seven columns (from A to G in the picture), and the combination of the first six columns (from A to F in the picture).

In this case you may use COUNTIFS as follows (I will use your same example CACACA):

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"C",B1:B6,"A",C1:C6,"C",D1:D6,"A",E1:E6,"C",F1:F6,"A",G1:G6,"2")/COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"C",B1:B6,"A",C1:C6,"C",D1:D6,"A",E1:E6,"C",F1:F6,"A")
```

The result will be 0.75, so if you want 75 you can just multiply the result by 100.

If you want to check the result also for CACACA 1, you just need to change the last value of the first COUNTIFS in the formula from "2" to "1" and you will get 0.25.

In case my understanding was wrong or you need more support do not hesitate to drop me a note!

Comment: exactly what i needed, I made a mistake to not go run through each column individually and did an array of all 6 columns. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: I replaced those "A" and "C" to reference cells and boom I got myself pattern recognize cells which can look up any pattern I want. Save a lot of time for me searching the database manually :)